# How to solve the problem of "isInitialized" in react js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

**This is an error in the App.js file present in the src of the main project file**

### This is the code snippet:

```
  15 | const [firebaseInitialized, setFirebaseInitialized] = useState(false);
  16 | 
  17 | useEffect(() => {
> 18 |   firebase.isInitialized().then(val => {
     | ^  19 |     setFirebaseInitialized(val);
  20 |   })
  21 |
```

Error in the following code is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'isInitialized' of undefined

What shall I do to solve this error?

Comment: i have imported firebase from 'firebase'

Comment: and in App.js i have imported firebase and firebase/auth

Comment: Have you ever execute `firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)` firstly? https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup?authuser=0#node.js-apps

Comment: yes in firebase.js

Comment: ok my problem was solved i removed the firebase/auth from import section.Thank you @StarkJeon for concerning.